# checkbox getlist return nothing - django

Tags: python, django

I have changed the button from checkbox to radio

I am using checkbox in this way:

```py
<input type="radio"name="group1"value="0">
<input type="radio"name="group1"value="1">
<input type="radio"name="group1"value="2">
<input type="radio"name="group1"value="3">
```

in my view.py

```py
boxes = request.POST.getlist("group1")
```

Which the boxes is an empty array. I have also tried:

```py
boxes = requset.POST.getlist("group1", [])
boxes = request.POST.getlist("group1[]")
boxes = request.POST("group1") <-- I have seen from other post said 
                                   this would only return the value
                                   the value of last element but I am also okay as the
                                   box will only have one box clicked
```

however, all of the above cannot successfully get the checkbox value.

---

Now I have found the problem since i am doing this way:

```html
<form id="submit_form" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}</form>
<div form="submit_form">
<input type="radio"name="group1"value="0">
<input type="radio"name="group1"value="1">
<input type="radio"name="group1"value="2">
<input type="radio"name="group1"value="3">
</div>
```

So it doesn't work.
I need to change it to

```html
<input form="submit_form" type="radio"name="group1"value="0">
<input form="submit_form" type="radio"name="group1"value="1">
<input form="submit_form" type="radio"name="group1"value="2">
<input form="submit_form" type="radio"name="group1"value="3">
```

But is there a better way to do it?

Comment: This seems like the wrong thing to do. Instead of using checkboxes and then adding some JS to ensure that only one is selected at a time, you should use the actual input type that is designed for that already: radio buttons.

Comment: but even if i change it to radio button, it still cannot get the value

Comment: Yes, that wasn't intended to be an answer, just a general comment. However I think you need to show the rest of the form and the view so we can understand what is going on.

Comment: actually this is my whole code as i test it on a new project

Comment: How can that be your whole code? Where is the rest of the HTML? Where is the view?

Comment: oh.... jesus... i found the problem. Coz I have a form outside the button so i need to add back form="the_form". But I am trying to use a <div form="the_form"> to include the whole radio button group so it doesnt work

Comment: Radio buttons with same name are not sent as list. If you want a list, you need to use checkbox i.e. `<input type="checkbox">`